# Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels random forrest

Tags: r

This is a code I am doing for an assignment. I cannot seem to get a confusion matrix for the predictions, please assist me with troubleshooting the code or make any recommendations necessary.

set.seed(1234)
`test_index1 <-createDataPartition(water_potability3$Potability,p=0.1,list= FALSE)`

`water_potability_train <- water_potability3[test_index1,-c(4,6:9)]`

`water_potability3_test<- water_potability3[!1:nrow(water_potability3)%in%test_index1,-c(4,6:9)]`

`<- tuneRF(x=water_potability_train[,1:4],y=water_potability_train$Potability) (mintree <-trf[which.min(trf[,2]),1])`
`<-randomForest(x=water_potability_train[,-5],y=water_potability_train$Potability,mtry = mintree,importance = TRUE)`

`(rf_model,main="")`
`(rf_model,main="")`

`preds_rf<- predict(rf_model,water_potability3_test[,-5])`

`table(preds_rf,water_potability3_test$Potability)`

`confusionmatrix(preds_rf,water_potability3_test$Potability)`

Everytime I do a confusion matrix I get the error "Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels"

Answer (score 0):

As you don't share a dataset that allows me to reproduce the error, I'm gonna have a guess and provide the solution I would have used myself. If this doesn't work for you, please provide some data and perhaps explain what the `Potability` column contains :-)

When randomly splitting the data into training and test partitions, you risk not having observations from every class in both partitions. E.g. if you have 10 classes, you might only have 8 of them in the smaller test partition. And then when your model predicts one of the two other classes that were available in the training partition, the two factors have different levels.

So I use `partition()` from `groupdata2` with the `cat_col` argument that ensures each class is represented in both partitions (if possible). Then I use `confusion_matrix()` from `cvms` as it allows different levels in the two factors.

```r
library(groupdata2)
library(cvms)
set.seed(1234) 

# Create list with two partitions
# where the ratio of classes in Potability are similar
parts <- partition(water_potability3[, -c(4,6:9)], 
                   p = 0.1, cat_col = "Potability")

# Extract the two partitions
water_potability3_test <- parts[[1]]
water_potability3_train <- parts[[2]]

# The modeling (haven't changed anything here)
trf <- tuneRF(x = water_potability_train[, 1:4],
              y = water_potability_train$Potability) 

(mintree <- trf[which.min(trf[, 2]), 1]) 

rf_model <- randomForest(
    x = water_potability_train[, -5],
    y = water_potability_train$Potability,
    mtry = mintree,
    importance = TRUE
)

preds_rf <- predict(rf_model, water_potability3_test[, -5])

# Create confusion matrix
conf_mat <- cvms::confusion_matrix(
    targets = water_potability3_test$Potability,
    predictions = preds_rf
)

# The basic confusion matrix table
conf_mat$Table

# Or as a plot
plot_confusion_matrix(conf_mat)
```

You may also check out `cvms::evaluate()` that has additional evaluation metrics.

#### Read more

More on the groupdata2 train/test partitioning functionality here:
https://cran.rstudio.com//web/packages/groupdata2/vignettes/cross-validation_with_groupdata2.html

More on the cvms confusion matrix functionality here:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cvms/vignettes/Creating_a_confusion_matrix.html